# Post Object field orderby (Advanced Custom Field)

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I created a Post Object field type (see attached screenshot post-object-0.png)

How do I output the instructors in order by the selection choices made by the users (see attached screenshot post-object.png)

My query is as follow:

```
$instructors = get_sub_field( 'instructors');
//var_dump( $instructors );
$total = count($instructors);

$posts = get_posts(array(
 'post_type' => 'kgi_personnel',
 'posts_per_page' => $total,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'include' => $instructors
));
```

Thank you in advance,

Ryan[image][image]

Comment: Change your field's return format to "Post Object" instead of "Post ID." That way you'll already have the post information in your `get_sub_field()` call and it will be in the order they selected.

Answer (score 3):

I actually added these 2 lines and it worked

```
'post__in' => $instructors,
'orderby' => 'post__in',
```